# When do we find out if SharePoint.StackExchange will be moving out of Beta?

Tags: discussion, beta

I see that we are now past the 90 days of beta.  I checked out the stats and most of them look good.

When do we find out if we are moving out of beta?

Answer (score 2):

At the end of the day it's a judgement call for the Stack Exchange team. However, a major indicator for them are [the site statistics on our Area 51 page](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/28921/).

If we can get each category to **Excellent**, then moving out of beta won't be too far away.

Also, please read [When Will My Site Graduate?](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/10/when-will-my-site-graduate/) on the Stack Exchange blog.

Comment: Well, we have 7k visits a day which should count extra. :)

Comment: Some sites stay in beta for a long time. Check out the [other beta site stats](http://area51.stackexchange.com/?tab=beta).

Comment: Time for another crack at those pesky unanswerred questions :-/

Comment: @SPDoctor, I have a feeling that a lot of those people won't accept no matter how good the answer is :(

Comment: @AbeMiessler True, but an accept is just 5 rep points more than an upvote (aside from the nice feeling of that tick). **We need more people to vote!** A [single upvote](http://meta.sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/305/is-it-useful-to-keep-poking-old-question-from-unknown-users/306#306) is all it takes for the system to categorise a question as 'answered'.

Comment: Apart from answerring, we can upvote *good* answers that have 0 votes, or if the question doesn't make sense flag it for deletion. I've answerred a few recently and nobody upvoted :-(  (hint, hint).

Answer (score 2):

SharePoint SE is one of those sites that was doing really well before it got hit with a summer slowdown. That's not unusual but there's a few other sites that came out in the queue to graduate before SharePoint. What we're watching for is **a bit more *steady* growth before committing** to a graduation date. Take a look at this blog post I just published.

[**Does this site have a chance of succeeding?**](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/does-this-site-have-a-chance-of-succeeding/)

**What you can work on** —

**82% questions answered** is "okay" but it is precariously close to the lower end of passable. SharePoint is such a good, custom fit for a Stack Exchange site, this community should definitely be able to do better.

A concerted effort to get those hardest-to-answer questions answered should help. But, after you exhaust all efforts to get your questions answered, this site might be **a good candidate for a cleanup effort.**

If there are a lot of questions which should have never have passed community scrutiny, now is a good time to start cleaning them up. This community is much stronger now, so it might be time to start a site-wide cleanup. If a question isn't worth answering (i.e. "unanswerable" as asked, or low quality), start ridding yourselves of that cruft. This is a very gross estimate — It looks like maybe the bottom ~5% to 10% of this site's questions are completely forgettable content that nobody would ever miss. Work at getting rid of that content that should have been removed long ago. That clean-up effort is best initiated and organized through a meta post. *Go for it.*

In the meantime, focus on keeping your quality high, look for opportunities to attract new users (like [Joel's OS X Lion initiative here](https://apple.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/589/now-that-lion-is-out-help-promote-ask-different)), and use those social bookmarks to promote your most intriguing content.

[image]

Comment: Thanks very much for your assessment Robert. We've been looking at [more ways to get questions answered](http://meta.sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/331/most-wanted-hitlist-of-unanswered-questions) and [how to improve our answered rate](http://meta.sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/261/how-can-we-improve-our-answered-site-statistics). A 'task force' type meta post could help too, we'll give that a try.

Comment: Maybe we could rally around the ability to have the site out of beta and promoting it at SPC2011?  I think we can get it out of beta well before then, but it does give us a target.

Comment: @RichRoss Great idea. I'll come up with a meta post for that.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at http://stackexchange.com/sites you can see a list that appears to be "ranked". We're up there with the sites that are out of beta, and you can see quite a few behind us that got de-beta-ified. I think percentage answered is the blocker - the StackExchange guy more-or-less said as much.

By the way, the main StackOverflow site has about 82% answered, by my calculations :-)